# Tensorflow numpy to tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, tensorflow

I have read a csv file using numpy `genfromtxt`

`csv_file = np.genfromtxt(args.dataset, delimiter=',',skip_header=1,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5), dtype=None)`

Ques: How to use string_input_producer to queue and batch the files.

Comment: Tell something about the resulting `csv_file` array.  dtype, shape?

Comment: @hpaulj 

`>>> type(csv_file)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

`csv_file.shape
(37810,)`

The csv has following fields

`Filename Annotation tag Upper left corner X Upper left corner Y Lower right corner X Lower right corner Y`

Comment: How about `dtype`?  That shape is 1d, so I suspect it is a structured array with multiple `fields`, not columns.  `dtype=None` gives you this.  What does `tensorflow` have to say about using structured arrays?

Comment: More on structured array - https://stackoverflow.com/q/44295375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a Numpy array from CSV as you do and chop it up into batches manually. However, TF has a built-in functionality of reading from multiple CSV files and putting rows together either into randomized or sequential batches. You can read cells of varying data-types and convert them into your relevant data-types as need be.

The working code to do this is discussed in this question:
[Converting TensorFlow tutorial to work with my own data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42302498/converting-tensorflow-tutorial-to-work-with-my-own-data/42373487?noredirect=1#comment71990719_42373487)

In a nutshell, the key functions you need are `tf.TextLineReader`, `tf.train.string_input_producer`, and `tf.train.shuffle_batch`, or `tf.train.batch`, depending on your needs.

The only limitation of that method that I'm aware of is that your rows within the CSV file should be of equal length.