# Convert numpy.void to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have loaded a .csv file in python with `numpy.genfromtxt`. Now it returns a 1 dimensional `numpy.ndarray` with in that array, `numpy.void` objects which are actually just arrays of integers. However I would like to convert these from type`numpy.void` to `numpy.array`. To clarify:

```
>>> print(train_data.shape)
(42000,)
>>> print(type(train_data[0]))
<class 'numpy.void'>
>>> print(train_data[0])
(9, 0, 0)
```

So here the array (9, 0, 0) which has type `numpy.void` should be a `numpy.array`.

How can I convert all values from `train_data` to be numpy arrays?

Efficiency is also somewhat important because I am working with a lot of data.

Some more code

```
>>> with open('filename.csv', 'rt') as raw_training_data:
>>>     train_data = numpy.genfromtxt(raw_training_data, delimiter=',', names=True, dtype=numpy.integer)
>>> print(train_data.dtype)
[('label', '<i4'), ('pixel0', '<i4'), ('pixel1', '<i4')]
>>> print(type(train_data))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: You should show the `genfromtxt` call.  What's `train_data.dtype`?  My guess it is a structured array.  It is 1d with multiple fields, which are accessed by field name.  Whether it is easy to convert to 2d numeric dtype will depend on the field dtypes.

Comment: @hpaulj I added the `train_data.dtype`.

Comment: `train_data['label']` is the first field, etc.  If you want a 2d array with 3 columns, try `skip_header=1` instead of `names=True`.  Since the fields are all `i4` we could convert this after loading, but loading in the desired format will be simpler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to slice a numpy.ndarray made up of numpy.void numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295375/how-to-slice-a-numpy-ndarray-made-up-of-numpy-void-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late to answer this. But found a solution for a similar problem I had, thanks to the solution provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295375/how-to-slice-a-numpy-ndarray-made-up-of-numpy-void-numbers).
If you can convert the train_data to list and then convert it to an numpy array, that would do the job for you.

```
print(np.array(train_data.tolist()).shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `numpy.asarray()` method, which converts an input to an array

```
array=numpy.asarray(train_data[0])
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I meant converting all 'void' arrays in the normal array. So by doing something creating an array with all numpy arrays in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling view with the correct dtype and shape, for your case you can do

```
 train_data= train_data.view((np.int_, 3))
```